# Namespace and inheritance

Tags: c++

I've got a namespace, with a class inside. As shown below;

```
class testClass {

public:
    testClass() { std::cout << "neat" << std::endl; };
    ~testClass() { };
    void print() {
        std::cout << "printOne" << std::endl;
    }

};

namespace test {
    class testClass;

    class testClassTwo {
    public:
        void printTwo() {
            std::cout << "printTwo" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
```

I know that I can inherit from the testClass using the normal way of

```
class testClassTwo : public testClass
```

But I've seen something along the line of what's within the namespace

```
class testClass;
```

I haven't been able to find a solid explanation of what this actually does, i'm assuming inheriting something from the testClass class.

I understand the simple stuff about namespaces such as;

```
test::testClassTwo classobj;
classobj.printTwo();
```

I can also compile;
    test::testClass;

but can't actually do anything with it.

Would anyone be able to forward me to some reading material or a quick explanation of what's actually going on when I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't been able to find a solid explanation of what this actually does, I'm assuming inheriting something from the testClass class.

That's an incorrect assumption. `class testClass` is a *forward declaration* of `testClass` data type. It lets you declare pointers and references to `testClass` objects without importing the corresponding header.

More information on forward declarations can be found in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757718/335858).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.
Where is it in the code?

In the code you pasted, it declares (tells the compiler) that a class called `testClass` exists in the `test` namespace.
(Read more: [*forward declaration*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration))

It should compile fine, but linking would throw an undefined rederence error.
There is no definition for `test::testClass`.

Comment: This is just a simple bit of code that I'm using to test things out, but seems like I was looking for forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
class testClass;
```

This is nothing more than a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration). Usually used to prevent circular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll get looking into forward declaration.